# Ninject how to check a binding for a given type is available without creating an instance

Tags: ninject, ninject-2

So I m just trying to test my modules, normally i would go and create a Kernel with the given module and then try to get an instance, however this scenario involves a few modules and it would be nicer if I could check that certain modules have access to certain Bindings (ie that implement and interface)

Is there any way to check if a binding for a given type is available without creating and instance of the class (ie so I don't have to make sure those dependencies are there)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Damn, of course as soon as I posted I found that in the Kernel, there is a `GetBindings()` method that does pretty much what I need.

Hope this helps to someone

Comment: Note that this won't tell you if a type can be resolved.  Missing-binding handler components can add additional as needed to satisfy requests, such as the self-binding handler.  But this will tell you if a binding has been registered.  Also, a binding may be conditional so even if a binding exists it may not be possible to resolve that type.

Comment: that is exactly what i want (not know if the type can be resolved). That way I don't need to load all dependencies into this kernel. Thanks for the note tho